# Edit button inside table row only works in consecutive order

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, submit

I am using php and javascript in order to display data from mysql in a table where each row must have an update button.

It seems to be working fine but i'm getting a weird behavior: it works when i click the buttons in consecutive order (#1 then #2 then #3..) but when i click them randomly (starting with #2 or #3...) it does nothing, just reloads the page.

Can you help me find what am i doing wrong, here's my code so far...
Thanks!

list.php:

```
<?php
    $q= "SELECT * FROM list WHERE id = $f ORDER BY id";

    if ($query = mysqli_query($db_con, $q)) {
        $y=1;
        echo '<table>'.
        '<tr>'.
        '<th>#</th>'.
        '<th>Name</th>'.
        '<th>Edit</th>'.
        '</tr>';

        while ($reg= mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$y.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$reg[0].'</td>';
            echo '<td>
            <form id="frm_data'.$y.'" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value="'.$reg[0].'" />
            <input type="hidden" id="f" name="f" value="'.$f.'" />
            <input type="hidden" id="a" name="a" value="'.$a.'" />
            <input id="FormSubmit" type="submit" value="EDIT">
            </form>
            </td></tr>';
            $y = $y +1;
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
?>
```

validate.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#FormSubmit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("#FormSubmit").hide();

            var myData = {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                a: $("#a").val(),
                f: $("#f").val()    
            };

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
                url: "update.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
                dataType:"json", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
                data:myData, //Form variables

                success : function(data) {
                    if(data.status == 'success'){
                        alert("OK!");
                    } else if(data.status == 'error') {
                        alert("ERROR!");
                    }
                },
                error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
    });
});
```

update.php

```
<?php
$f = $_POST["f"];                           
$name = $_POST["name"]; 
$q = "UPDATE list SET edited = '1' WHERE id = '$f' AND name = '$name'   ";

$update_row = mysqli_query($db_con, $q);

if (!$update_row) {
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';   
} else {
    $response_array['status'] = 'success'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Just one quick notice on the code. An ID of the form should always be the same regardless of a database ID so you can always check if that form submitted. Now for the dbid you can include a hidden input.

Comment: Add an `alert` window just before `jQuery.ajax({` to display `myData`, then click the EDIT buttons randomly to see if the data displayed matches the data of the submit button been clicked.

Comment: Jose, i did that and "name" is always taking the first value of the list.. any idea why? thanks...

Comment: thanks Jose, the problem was that <id="name"> must be a unique value, so i changed it for something like <id="name-'.$reg[0].'"> and got the values from there instead of a <form>